# Produto cartesiano Proposital

Tags: sql, firebird

Eu precisario criar um produto cartesiano proposital, para um relatório em Fast reports
ou seja multiplicar meus dados por um numero determinado
EX:

```
select
  cli.cdclifor,
  CLI.nmCliFor
from
  cadclifor cli
where  cli.cdclifor = '000001'
```

resultado:

```
000001 Jõao das Couves
```

gostaria que me retornasse

resultado:

```
000001 Jõao das Couves
000001 Jõao das Couves
000001 Jõao das Couves
```

Comment: pois é cara os dados são somente da cadclifor, uso um JOIN quando tenho mais de uma tabela, até tentei fazer um mas n deu muito certo

Comment: Tente deixar a pergunta mais completa, clique no [edit] e acrescente a estrutura da tabela e mais detalhes do que precisa, que aumenta a chance de uma boa resposta. Por exemplo, o que determina que saiam 3 resultados em vez de um?

Comment: traria Jõao das Couves, Jõao das Couves Jõao das Couves,..... eu vou dizer o número de resultados mas enfim e pra uma etiqueta em fast Reports

Comment: O seguinte como é para um Relatório em Fast Reports, e o mesmo suporta Script irei passar o numero de vezes que quero repetir o valor para o relatório, e criar um script no Fast que faça um for adicionando UNION ALL select ... repetindo assim o número de vezes que quero, assim que pronto posto aqui como ficou.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso que eu vou escrever pode parecer absurdo, mas é prática comum em técnicas de [*Data Mining*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minera%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_dados) (em contraste com sistemas transacionais "normais", onde isso seria considerado um WTF):

Simplesmente crie uma tabela para representar números, e faça um produto cartesiano (`cross join`) com essa tabela:

```
create table numeros(
  numero integer
);

insert into numeros(numero) values(1);
insert into numeros(numero) values(2);
insert into numeros(numero) values(3);
...
(até onde você espera razoavelmente que você precisará consultar)

select
  cli.cdclifor,
  cli.nmCliFor
from
  cadclifor cli
  cross join numeros n
where  cli.cdclifor = '000001' and n.numero <= 3;
```

[Exemplo no SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ff7ec/2/0). Pode ser que existam soluções melhores (pelo menos assim eu espero!) mas infelizmente não conheço nenhuma...